# Dell Latitude D830 laptop - disable touchpad

Tags: touchpad, dell-latitude

The touch pad is a real pain because it seems to pickup my hand as I'm typing.  I never use it the touchpad, I prefer using the the finger pointer on the keyboard between letters G-H-B.

Is there a way to disable the touchpad?

I guess I don't understand exactly what I should be downloading from the dell site? I have a Dell D830 running XP.  I searched for TouchPad Applications but I get a list of different programs and drivers drivers. Is there not some easier way to just disable my TouchPad gone rogue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have the "Dell Touchpad" icon in the System Tray, near the clock?

[image]

If yes,

- Right-click on it and select "Touchpad Properties"
- Click on "Device Select"
- Set the "Touchpad" to "Disable"

If you don't have the icon, you can install the Dell Touchpad application from Dell's website (link [**here**](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R165804&SystemID=LATITUDE%20D830&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=14029&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=17&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=223709)).

Comment: Didn't have the application installed. Downloaded it. Installed it. Disabled the stupid touchpad. Yay!

Comment: The driver does not work for 64Bit systems, but you can use the Latitude 6400 driver: ftp://ftp.us.dell.com/input/Dell_Touchpad----Pointing-St_A14_R270649.exe

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it on my D830 latitude by downloading the Dell driver but had to select Vista as they say Win 7 is not supported.  It worked anyway.