# Disable touchpad on Dell Latitude E4300, but don't disable the trackpoint

Tags: touchpad, dell-latitude

For the last 6 years I have been using a ThinkPad R50e which used a trackpoint instead of a touchpad.

Now though I am using a laptop given to me by my work and it's a Dell Latitude E4300 which utilises both a trackpoint and a touchpad for mouse gestures. However, I'm finding the touchpad troublesome as a lot of the time I end up touching the touchpad while using the trackpoint and it in turn triggers events that I don't want or didn't expect.

Is it at all possible to disable the touchpad while continuing to use the trackpoint?

Answer (score 2):

The key to these settings should be the "Dell Touchpad" application. If it is installed, you can access it either by the system tray or "Control panel -> Mouse". See [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/112941/dell-latitude-d830-laptop-disable-touchpad), too - containing a screenshot of the application:

[image]

If it's not installed yet, it should be possible to download it from Dell, [this link](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&DriverId=R155586) seems to point to an old download (2007), but it might work.

Comment: Downloaded it but it doesn't want to install. It comes with the error "Could not find OS specific setup program". I've changed the compatibility to Windows Vista but no good. :(

Comment: Did you go to the Dell site and enter a service tag?  That usually works but sometimes you need to use just the model group and then the needed install will be listed.  Have seen this with WiFi adapters.

Comment: Did work for me, trackpoint + external mouse w/o touchpad is great